# Regular expression to end when it sees a number?

Tags: regex

So right now im trying to create a regex that takens in ID's. The ID is a string so it can have letters and numbers. However, i need to make an expression to see that it gets digits, it should not take in letters anymore and end the expression.

What i have:

```
[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])*
```

Example:

```
"Bob23Dan"
```

Example answer:

```
1) "Bob23"
2) "Dan"
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Victor I guess he wants a working regex?

Comment: Need to create or modify the regular expression above to take in a string and not accept any letters after it receives digits.

Comment: End after the first set of digit(s), or can there be more than one, as in `Bob23Dan24Fred`?

Comment: @Johnware. Just looking for it to end after the first set of digits. So  the example you posted above would be split into 3

Comment: @Rob it's OK to strip "I" from the question title, but there's no need to omit it in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match a variable number of letters (atleast one) that ends with a variable number of numbers (optional)

```
[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate there being letters after the digits in the original string, but you just don't want to match them, then I think you need this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+
```

which will take in any number of letters from the start of the string (`^`), then at least one digit. It will fail to match if there are no digits, but pass if there are digits but no letters.

If you want to make sure there are no letters after the digits in the original string (the purpose of the regex is to test rather than to match), then append the end of line char (`$`) like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+$
```